# realizar una operacion llamando solo a la clase y no al metodo

Tags: python

Tengo una duda respecto a clases en python, deseo que al llamar a una clase ya no sea necesario el llamar al metodo para realizar lo que busco, creo que lo mas facil es explicar con un ejemplo:

```
class Suma:
    def __init__(self, primer_numero, segundo_numero):
        self.primer_numero = primer_numero
        self.segundo_numero = segundo_numero

    def realizar_suma(self):
        return self.primer_numero + self.segundo_numero
```

Tengo esta clase que normalmente si deseo realizar una suma seria de esta forma:

```
suma = Suma(3,4)
resultado = suma.realizar_suma()
print(resultado)
```

pero lo que busco es que simplemente con llamar a la clase se guarde el resultado de la suma y me lo regrese

```
suma = Suma(3,4)
print(suma)
```

Mencionar que en las clases que ocupo aplicar esto solo tienen un metodo cada clase entonces no realizan ninguna otra cosa.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres es algo interesante, pues normalmente eso lo hacen las funciones, pero con algún *truco* podemos hacer lo mismo.

Al guardar en una variable la clase, lo que te regresa es su instancia, o en todo caso, la definición de la clase, la cual podemos ver haciendo `print(Suma(2,3))`

```py
print(Suma(2,3))

#resultado
<__main__.Suma object at 0x7f80abe0aed0>
```

Para hacer lo que pides haremos uso del *dunder method* `__repr__` el cual devuelve un string que será el que se mostrara al hacer un `print()`

```py
class Suma:
    def __init__(self, primer_numero, segundo_numero):
        self.primer_numero = primer_numero
        self.segundo_numero = segundo_numero

    def realizar_suma(self):
        return self.primer_numero + self.segundo_numero
    
    def __repr__(self):
        #realizamos la suma
        suma = sum([self.primer_numero,self.segundo_numero])
        return f"{suma}"
```

Ahora si podemos hacer lo que quieres

```py
suma = Suma(2,3)
print(suma)
#salida-> 5

print(Suma(3,3))
#salida-> 6
```

Sin embargo como dije esto es solo la representación de la clase, antes se mostraba asi: `<__main__.Suma object at 0x7f80abe0aed0>` y ahora se muestra así `6`, ademas hay que recordar que el resultado devuelto por `__repr__` es un string. Si tartas de hacer

```py
suma = Suma(2,3)
suma = suma+1
print(suma)
```

Te devolverá un error y no será por operar un string con un entero sino que será `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Suma' and 'int'` diciendo que no puedes operar entre una variable de tipo `Suma` un numero. Al crear una clase, lo que pasa es que se crea un nuevo tipo de dato.

No se si tienes mal el concepto de *Clase* y *funcion* pero lo mas recomendable es hacer una función que solo se encargue de sumar.

```py
def suma(a,b):
    return a+b
```